# Go compiler says "declared and not used" but they are being used

Tags: compiler-errors, go

I have the following function that is giving me "variable declared and not used" errors:

```
type Comparison struct {
        Left []byte
        Right []byte
        Name string
}

func img(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, c appengine.Context, u *user.User) {
  key := datastore.NewKey("Comparison", r.FormValue("id"), 0, nil)
  side := r.FormValue("side")
  comparison := new(Comparison)
  err := datastore.Get(c, key, comparison)
  check(err)

  if( side == "left"){
    m, _, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewBuffer(comparison.Left))
  } else {
    m, _, err := image.Decode(bytes.NewBuffer(comparison.Right))
  }
  check(err)

  w.Header().Set("Content-type", "image/jpeg")
  jpeg.Encode(w, m, nil)
}
```

It gives me the following errors:

```
dpcompare.go:171: m declared and not used
dpcompare.go:171: err declared and not used
dpcompare.go:173: m declared and not used
dpcompare.go:173: err declared and not used
dpcompare.go:178: undefined: m
dpcompare.go:185: key declared and not used
```

The thing is `m`, `err`, and `key` are all being used. I can't wrap my head around why the compiler thinks thy are not.

Comment: The error messages tell the whole story. m is declared on both lines 171 and 173, so those must be different instances of m, and different from the one on line 178 as well, which is undefined. Likewise, err is declared on lines 171 and 173, so those can't be the same instance of err declared previously on line 167. You would get similar messages in C++, C99, or Java if you multiply declared variables with the same name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @kostix said, `m` is local to the scope of the `if`. Try this code

```
type Comparison struct {
        Left []byte
        Right []byte
        Name string
}

func img(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, c appengine.Context, u *user.User) {
  key := datastore.NewKey("Comparison", r.FormValue("id"), 0, nil)
  side := r.FormValue("side")
  comparison := new(Comparison)
  err := datastore.Get(c, key, comparison)
  check(err)

  // NOTE! now m is in the function's scope
  var m Image    
  if( side == "left"){
    m, _, err = image.Decode(bytes.NewBuffer(comparison.Left))
  } else {
    m, _, err = image.Decode(bytes.NewBuffer(comparison.Right))
  }
  check(err)

  w.Header().Set("Content-type", "image/jpeg")
  jpeg.Encode(w, m, nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That *mostly* solved my issues. I'm still getting the error about key. Is it possible that key is a reserved word? Key is only used in the one scope...

Comment: Nevermind. It was totally pebkac on the key error. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the variables you declare in those `if` branches are local to the code blocks of these branches. This is not JavaScript (luckily). So just declare your variables somewhere above `if` and use `=` instead of `:=` to assign to them.

Comment: Simple assignment uses "="; ":=" is an initialising declaration, so "x := 0" means "var x = 0".